# Solving $2^x+2^{3x}=16$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

> Solve $$2^x+2^{3x}=16$$

My attempt:

The simplest form of this equation I could obtained after simplification is $1+2^{2x}=2^{4-x}$. I couldn't find the value of $x$

My conclusion:

Either the question is wrongly framed or there is no solution.

Comment: Well, you can write $y=2^x$, resulting in a cubic equation for $y$. Then you can solve for $y$ using the formula for roots of a cubic.  Not sure that that will give you a super nice-looking result, though.

Comment: Please note that this is not a [linear-algebra] problem. Consider using [algebra-precalculus] instead.

Comment: There are no integer solutions. There is a solution between $1$ and $2$ but there may be no closed solution. Where did you get this problem?

Comment: @JohnDouma somebody has forwarded hand written question in my watsaap

Comment: @gete Do you know what class they are taking? This could be a Newton's method problem or something like that.

Comment: @JohnDouma: It is about solving the equation $y+16=y^3$. $y=1/3 (216 - 3 (\sqrt{5181})^(1/3) + (72 + \sqrt{5181})^(1/3)/3^(2/3)$, $x=\log_2y$.

Comment: Let $y=2^x$. Then, the equation becomes $y+y^3=16$ (not $y+16=y^3$ as markvs had stated).

Comment: @JohnDouma this is a question from secondary level

Comment: @gete: *"this is a question from secondary level"* Please add all context to the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden (or moved).

Comment: Now I see solution of this question using Cardon's formula, but this method is not feasible for secondary grade students

Comment: @gete: OK, $y= (72 + \sqrt{5187})^{1/3}/3^{2/3} - (3 (72 + \sqrt{5187}))^{-1/3}$

Comment: @gete: Is it possible the hand-written "$+$" was meant to be "$\times$"? Of course, that makes the problem *very* easy to solve. Is this a textbook exercise, or could your Whatsapp correspondent have simply been thinking-out-loud about, say, what happens when you change "$\times$" to "$+$"?

Comment: @Blue the sender also has no idea about this equation. The one who forwarded this message to me is a college lecturer in Botany, and he has received this question from a school teacher who teaches secondary level students. So, I think that if the question is correct, then there might be a simpler solution without using Cardon's formula and logarithm

Comment: Logarithm is unavoidable. However, in this special case, you can change variable to a variable $u$ defined by the relation: $2^x = y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(u - \frac1u)$. You equation reduces to $\frac1{\sqrt{3}}(u^3 - \frac1{u^3}) = 16$, a quadratic equation in $u^3$. This is perfectly acceptable for secondary students in math (in most part of the world).

Comment: oops, should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}^\color{red}{3}}(u^3 - \frac{1}{u^3}) = 16$

Comment: For future reference, you probably shouldn't say things like "I couldn't solve this, so I conclude the question is wrong". In this case you may be right that it is "wrong" for a secondary school level question, in the sense that it can't be solved by secondary-school-level methods, but the question is certainly solvable as others have indicated. I would guess this is the reason behind the down- and close votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2^x+2^{3x}=16$$
Let $u=2^x$
$$\implies u+u^3=16$$
solve $u^3+u-16=0$ using [Newton–Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) you get :
$$u\approx 2.38768$$
$$2^x=2.38768$$
$$\boxed{x=1.25561}$$

Answer (score -1):

So this is what I did:
[hand worked problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Je3.jpg)

After finding y this should be easy.
I followed the cubic formula found in the next link: [Cubic Formula](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/)

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Sorry, new here. Will do next time

Answer (score -1):

Plotting both functions, we see that there is a solution on $[1,2]$. My initial feeling is that we can only find the solution by using a computer.

[image]